# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in XXX.exe

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unhandled-exception, executionengineexception

I have a DLL file that is written in C++. I am try to use in C++ DLL in my c# code. C++ method is called correctly but it gives error after process completed.

**Exception Details:**

> completed.System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
>   Message=Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was
>   thrown.

Comment: It would help if you could show us the `Message` and `StackTrace` fields of the `ExecutionEngineException`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.executionengineexception.aspx

Comment: do you have a debug version of the C++ dll? if yes you can debug it. You can also use Microsoft Debugging Tools for windows to create an application dump.

Comment: This usually means that there is a memory corruption bug in the unmanaged DLL, and it is corrupting the engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem with this code:

```
    [DllImport("camapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern CSTATUS_T CWRAPPER_GetFriendlyName(IntPtr pCameraBus, string sCamID, out StringBuilder sFriendlyName, 
                                                         uint uBufferSizeInWords);

public static string CWRAPPER_GetFriendlyName(IntPtr pCameraBus, string sCamID)
{
    var sFriendlyName = new StringBuilder(256);
    var status = CWRAPPER_GetFriendlyName(pCameraBus, sCamID, out sFriendlyName, (uint)s.Capacity + 1);
    return (status == CSTATUS_T.CSTATUS_SUCCESS) ? sFriendlyName.ToString() : "";
}
```

The problem was the "out" keyword.  The example on MSDN doesn't have the 'out'.

Hope that helps someone...
Simon